# Google Express Sand box environment

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-shopping

I am trying to integrate the Google Express with my Magento store. Whenever the user placed an order in GE, I need to pull that data and create the corresponding order in my Magento application. I am using the information from https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/reference/v2/orders/list to get the order list. But before that I want know is there any test/sand-box environment available for listing my products in GE and able to place a test order?

Answer (score 1):

Try this URL for the Sandbox mode access to the API:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/content/v2sandbox/content.orders.list